# Error aroused when installing pymol on CentOS 7 from source

Tags: centos7, pymol

I am trying to intall pymol on my centos 7 system from source using the mothed discribed at pymolwiki (https://pymolwiki.org/index.php/Linux_Install)
Everything was ok until I run install script:

```
#!/bin/bash -e

prefix=/opt/pymol-svn
modules=$prefix/modules

# If you want to install as root, then split this line up in "build"
# and "install" and run the "install" with "sudo"
python2.7 setup.py build install \
    --home=$prefix \
    --install-lib=$modules \
    --install-scripts=$prefix
```

I got a error message and the installation process was terminated:

In file included from contrib/mmtf-c/mmtf_parser.cpp:31:0:
contrib/mmtf-c/mmtf_parser_private.h:38:23: fatal error: msgpack.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include 
                       ^
compilation terminated.

I then installed msgpack by yum command and tried to run the pymol install script again, but the same error still occurred.

I googled this problem but cannot find a answer. Could anyone help me here?

Best regards.

Yeping Sun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the developer package of msgpack installed.

```
yum install msgpack-devel.x86_64
```

Fixed it for me.

There were a few other ways of doing it listed here:

https://sourceforge.net/p/pymol/mailman/message/35883233/